# Neumann expansion of seemingly simple series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, bessel-functions

I know there is this Neumann expansion (Watson - A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions p.525)
$$
z^\nu = \Gamma(\nu+1) \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!} \, J_{\nu+n}(2z)
$$
where $J$ is the Bessel function.

I'm now wondering if there is also such a relation (closed form) for the similar looking expression
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!} \, J_{\nu+n}(2z)
$$
or likewise without faculty
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n \, J_{\nu+n}(2z) \, .
$$

Thanks for input.